# Video Streaming in Android using Lighttpd

Tags: android, video, streaming, lighttpd

I 'm developing a video streaming android application on HTC Tattoo. I 've Lighttpd server at my server side which i use to stream videos to a web site. 
On Android , Do I need to enable any module in Lighttpd server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually, no... the only thing you have to make sure is that the video you are serving is encoded with one of this formats: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look also at Darwin Streaming Server. Perhaps it will be good option for mobile streaming.

Comment: Ok will give a try to Darwin streaming server also. Thanks